# Solve for z in form a+bi

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

$\frac{z+2-4i}{z}=5-4i$
$z+2-4i=z(5-4i)$
$z+2-4i=5z-4iz$
$z+4iz-5z=-2+4i$
$-4z+4iz=-2+4i$

Am I doing this correctly? And what do I do from here. I need to get the I to the other side but don't know how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So far, so good. You might want to put a cross-line in your Zs because they look like $2$s.

Comment: If I'm reading your problem correctly you have: $-4z + 4iz = -2 + 4i$.  So $z(-4 + 4i) = -2+4i$ so $z = \frac {-2+4i}{-4+4i}$.  Do you know how to simplify that last bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$z=\frac{-2+4i}{-4+4i}=\frac{(-2+4i)(-4-4i)}{(-4+4i)(-4-4i)}$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yessir I appreciate it